# With Glass, is it possible to use head tilt to interact with Glassware? (e.g. nod to move on to next card?)

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

I'm pretty sure it's not at this point, but just want to double check. Are there any possible creative workarounds?

Comment: this is a legit programming question... some of the built in google UI responds to head titling.  the @user wants to know if 3rd parties can build their own apps "glassware" that do the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't available at all in Glassware, but it is with the GDK.

The tilt isn't available as its own discrete gesture, but if you're programming in the GDK you can access the accelerometer and use its data to determine head tilt. Or you might try the Gyroscope. In onSensorChanged you'll have to determine how much the head is tilted against your target threshold, and trigger your code to navigate accordingly from there.

https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/location-sensors/index#sensors

Answer (score 1):

There is definitely nothing like that in the current  documentation